# Not able to display images with imageView in swift

Tags: swift, image, imageview, size

I have confirmed the images are targeted in the project and are able to show in bigger image view.

> Could not load the "red_check" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier ""

Though there is one more thing  to add: I have made another StoryBoard named `LoginStoryBoard.Story`. And is being referenced from View Controller as follows:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       
    }
  
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboard.LoginStoryboard , bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: StoryboardId.loginVC)
   
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
          navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
            }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
           navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
       
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: What does 'p' standard for?  Pixels?  Points?

Comment: Something doesn't sound right. Could you provide more details? Maybe something that we could duplicate? My first though if how you are setting the `.contentMode` property - but that also doesn't make much sense. So my focus would be on the error *...image referenced from a nib..."? What are you trying to do? Pull an image from another view?

Comment: thanks for Helping Guys !!! p stands for pixels and Image Views are Constrained in StoryBoard and are given default values in The story board

Comment: The images are imported in Assets.xcassets